# Altair: Using x-axis value for tooltip title

Tags: tooltip, altair

Brand spanking new to Altair. Trying to do something that *seems* like it should be straightforward, but I'm hitting a wall.

Trying to get the title of a tooltip to be the x-axis value.[image]

Code's fairly straightforward:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": ["Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent"],
    "y": [0, 1, 3, 0, 12],
    "color": ["#356FC7", "#82AAE3", "#33578D", "#CBCBCB", "#90959B"]
})

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().properties(
    height=200,
    width=200
).encode(
    x=alt.X("x:N", sort=None),
    y=alt.Y("y:Q"),
    color=alt.Color("color:N", scale=None),
    tooltip=[alt.Tooltip("y", title="x")]
)
```

Rather than the hard-coded "x" for the title, how can I get the tooltip to use the x-axis value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can change titles dynamically like that. Do you specifically want to include the x value as the title or would you be ok with setting `tooltip=['x', 'y']`?

Comment: Hey @joelostblom. I was specifically looking to include the x value as the title. If that can't be done, `tooltip=['x','y']` is an option. Or I might just look at removing the title attribute altogether.

Comment: The issue with removing the title using `title=''` is that you would still end up with a free floating `:` which I didn't see an immediate way to remove. Maybe having more meaningful column names that 'x' and 'y' would be the most subtle solution even if it results in more text in the tooltip.

Comment: @joelostblom I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69996666/12511801) - not sure if you've read it - , but, as I read the comments here, it seems is not possible for my case scenario.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I was just writing a reply to your question actually!