# Customize tooltip in Altair chart

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, altair

I'm using Google Colab for learning Python. In this [Google Colab notebook I've built for demostration](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iAMri5g6F8U3usC2AjZ-9EJ5P0zAWKW8?usp=sharing), I was able to get some JSON data and visualize it with [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/interactive_brush.html).

This is the chart image I got so far - you can interact with the data in the [linked Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iAMri5g6F8U3usC2AjZ-9EJ5P0zAWKW8?usp=sharing) or directly in the [vega-editor ready with the sample data](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-tDUZKYe15tgJMAaluAHID7c9wAKE+UaOUEqzE9Dke-Ti3O+1361gpQBBMfRWR-P1-vz9GAASluABeUCD0ofcQIAfluC8PCvKIbz-VZHwsX913vVY32GQDvxAr0EKQlCsJfNDvUwwgN3-PCmCAoCJyna5jgXcAez7AdFUoAA1ap6FvMi2Vgg9Dz3Z82WPW4TxTPiajoQTqJHOg8RE-cAHoxKfMiVMeL192g259OndTuX3JidF5PkAH0yUpaRIxAAASbVGEwSIdDEQgkkoZB1PUjFg1rBAzkYaNazgCB1Nc9yFACoMQxqIYApYWsbFrKxawAK0oCV5CUSca2NUAxiMUxLFsBwnBcNxPG8Xx-CsQJglCU1QFqZAbBMCQrB8QxuDHNYACFcjKfRSQSTA7moRgziTYlmwQPLOlWHQLFuad22qANoCvZU9RANlJA4DpdJQCwzA4bgCgxIFOu4LcSUW5alGvDxSFXNIABkAEkAHFBEuCcojANyITSEaxomqb3nag4WGMQJjBYKwWAGucdGJaIYgDBQQrAOBkQJVa0nWzaokiXIdqgPaogOo7kAuq7cXxRmrGZm7QRQewHoUbcdAAZRSfJnlpidCDej6SW5AAlAVuGiUGaxJkAsdiXH8cJqBYZADqLER4ILBMdHxzSBbME0fsoCKDkVfWoXQSpt0q3pwg4mQepcnkPE6j7L2QE5u7Pd5-m0nJFlxclz7g8OkGwZJz22I6mw2DMCQLpsHm1AxtJSX2ZVblJFFEg2-dCEoA7wZAKxbnJKhIqzf1dqGZYFbd87LtOn3kCsdprswW7WBDtZyWLKJqTbqO1l+gGgYVuPle+RPODh86pBsTuMOz02Z2HDwC+MGwvQF5EvnTa3szc24BZiBJbgABWQ3LtdtuF1oADQATQALWp2nXfdtYZmZ1Gb2A5gPLm90QCPR0DLCAYB2SHQlshd6n1Vay3lrHJW4Nl6r2QGYQwLB7CGFTh0QaOhpx7wLvYKwXoZaYA8NELW19PixGJm-W4X9f5Nxpi3ABKAu6s3aB0QOkhh6Y2ei-JBU8dDUF5KSGWwNsEJz9knA4EhLDGF9AQk2ax74QEIPcR4xIppwETJXO219hZO3dOLd2McQEx1ER7P24i0jk0ppHFBUtfYNCwfHOEf1EyFB1nrCwNhjAWBYGYNG289FRAgFCO+C08bLSrjXL6JAcY8LFm3d2qNgHdycRAoOrjoF8zWC6BI+86aYmkd4tBM9AZKICakRO1ppBAA):

[image: Chart results so far:]

Below is the explanation of the data I have and what I want to show:

> In Yu-Gi-Oh! TCG, cards came from a certain card set. In each card set are Monster, Spell and Trap cards - as well another type of cards like: Link Monsters, XYZ monsters, etc.

A *normal* JSON structure of a monster card (*- for this purpose - has ATK and DEF*) has the following JSON structure:

```
{
   "id":89631139,
   "name":"Blue-Eyes White Dragon",
   "type":"Normal Monster",
   "atk":3000,
   "def":2500,
   "level":8,
   "race":"Dragon",
   "attribute":"LIGHT",
   "archetype":"Blue-Eyes"
}
```

But, a non-monster card (*i.e. a spell card*) has no values neither in ATK and DEF attributes:

*Example:*

```
{
   "id":35261759,
   "name":"Pot of Desires",
   "type":"Spell Card",
   "race":"Normal",
   "archetype":"Greed"
}
```

I want to visualize in the chart each card that comes in the card set and - while the cursor is on a point (*hover*), it will show the details of the card like, (*Name, ATK, DEF (if any) and the Type of card*).

*Example of desired tooltip:*

[image: Desired tooltip]

After some trial and error, research and read the documentation, I'm facing the following issues and wondering if the results I'm looking are possible:

- When you hover on a point that does not have ATK and DEF - (*see image 1*) = how to modify the settings of Altair chart for condition the build of the tooltip? - see image 1:

*Image 1*:

[image: Image 1]

*In "image 1", the card called "Pot of Desires" is a Spell Card = it doesn't have ATK or DEF, I've configured the chart with the [invalid property](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/mark.html) for shown Nulll / None / NaN values) and Altair sets 0 as default to those missing values*.

The expected output in (*for a non-monster card*) would be:

> Name: Pot of Desires
>
> Type: Spell Card

The expected output in (*for a monster card*) would be:

> Name: Blue-Eyes White Dragon
>
> ATK: 3000 - DEF: 2500
>
> Type: Normal Monster

The expected output in (*for a link monster card* = has `ATK`, but no `DEF`) would be:

> Name: Proxy Dragon
>
> ATK: 3000
>
> Type: Link Monster

I want to condition how to build the tooltip in these scenarios, it is possible?

Comment: I read the intent of the question as wanting to change what the tooltip displays depending on the data point being hovered over. Normally, if you specify a column name as a list, it will display the value along with the column name. I don't have any experience with this.

Comment: @r-beginners you read my question well, sorry if I can't express myself better. If you consider [edit] my question for make it cleared, it would be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, see https://github.com/vega/vega-tooltip/issues/251. In summary it seems like Vega and VegaTooltip does remove fields with `Undefined` form the tooltip, but VegaLite forces these to be shown in the tooltip (compare [this VegaLite spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckAIJgE6Asl2Ex3PJcTcA7oyXUwL3bGSE3WzB0JU0wVEYxHTBCINoxByVYOjUNSE1rTBxgSAp0MVYdbDAAbQ0IUAgISCyARnUqqHZsc1TGyHgWgC1IcrAAXwaqyqqa7Gkh6uasSAANXsbBvpHqrIAmSahOmZ7N9Jb2dF0Fqv6QAF0QJeqMXQBrYsgAjzw2qGQleG5ND2pilagAA9-pAAGaMZBiTSPTCqKB4ACesUeAEdWCEjHhrIwqJBrqM8NxuGIjIRimVGhUwRCoTC1PCkchUeilJjsbj8Y0cuDIdDTM04ZBEcjTEpuBElPk8ZsqTzaaZOoLhUzReKPFLOcNqbzHtClYzHmKJRq+ucwBozmcgA) with [this Vega one](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgFY6AK1jcAdpAA04KABNkCAE6NCeHnJyQAgmAToCydYQA23PMcTcA7oxnUw99bGSFH5sOhnKYKiMlmpghL60ltYysHQKSpDs6PAA1tTq3KwB2FAOiMzICRCQhOjKys7UuaKKJU7KLLkATAAMrXW4yIzU+C0dibB4AJ6huZDwyNHFKqaYOADaShCgEGtQMuioRfrSrOqTAPqtM+uQFOiWrGq5S+vrwJDzYACM8lDs4wYKUPDjAFqQAC+nXuYEezwAzO8kuMABrA0H3CEtGF-fSAmHKcbJdTA5ZrAC6BJBBNW90gm2242Uc2OpzWkD2Bx2UGZRxOSJKeHU-lgADNuOpULcCQ8xRSRhFxvyQnhzAywZBkAAPQh4-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-TDP0SYQgNIrEFICDWhtRClWUCL0Ci4jLk8NLLHQdgpgrMB+Ru5A0owFUAFEVXlNaLw+5wfr+9aBiVHQ0me16E3e6taucVR5KskkkT6koBp87sRrG-QOwIKa0pm5Loduha8CUp5u3ux7LBdK5YEQObYaVampgAeSodR7vQnBquZyVFpW7J1seTaCt+bpLD2-UWEO47TopeGAlVC9WrAZyJlkWVqifZI0gyVbksgfJCnxIEgA)). It seems like they are looking for help to implement the feature you want.

Here is an example with your data that illustrates how both `null` and `Undefined` values show up in the tooltip:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{
   "id":89631139,
   "name":"Blue-Eyes White Dragon",
   "type":"Normal Monster",
   "atk":3000,
   "def":2500,
   "level":8,
   "race":"Dragon",
   "attribute":"LIGHT",
   "archetype":"Blue-Eyes"
},
{
   "id":35261759,
   "name":"Pot of Desires",
   "type":"Spell Card",
   "race":"Normal",
   "archetype":"Greed"
}])

alt.Chart(df).mark_point(tooltip={'content': 'data'}).encode(
    x='name',
    y='type'
).transform_calculate(
   A = "isValid(datum.atk) ? datum.atk : 'Undefined'",
   D = "isValid(datum.def) ? datum.def : 'Undefined'"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I posted an answer below and a issue on Github https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7811 - hope it helps to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@joelostblom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70009390/12511801), my case scenario is not possible - yet - let's hope this scenario could be more common in order to raise more attention of the pull request/feature I've created - https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7811.

Meanwhile, the accepted answer is: *is not possible*, but, I'll checking for new answers and possible solutions.

---

That being said, I decide to check further and share my findings here:

- Using [Vega Expressions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/), I tried to customize the tooltip data and I got pretty good results, IMHO, but, not as close as I intended.

Here are the results I mentioned:

[image: Result with transform.calculate]

The Python code of the previous chart is as follows:

```
# V.2 of the chart/graph:
alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=200, filled=True, invalid=None, tooltip={'content': 'data'}).encode(
          x={"field": "def", "type": "quantitative", "title": "DEF"}, 
          y={"field": "atk", "type": "quantitative", "title": "ATK"}, 
          color={"field": "type", "type": "nominal", "title": "Types of cards"}, 
          shape="type"
      ).properties(
          title={
              "text": ["Cardset: " + cardSetName], 
              "subtitle": ["Here is shown the " + str(len(df.index)) + " card" + ('s' if len(df.index) > 1 or str(len(df.index)) == 0 else '') + " contained in the cardset."]
              }
          ).transform_calculate(
          Name = "datum.name",
          Type = "datum.race + ' ' + ((substring(datum.type, datum.type.length-1, datum.type.length) == 's') ? substring(datum.type, 2, datum.type.length-1) : substring(datum.type, 2, datum.type.length))",
          ATK_DEF = "isValid(datum.atk) ? '' + datum.atk + (isValid(datum.def) ? '/' + datum.def : '') : 'N/A'"
          ).interactive()
```

- The rest of the data is added thanks to `tooltip={'content': 'data'}` configuration. *If there would be a way to declare the fields to use only in the tooltip*, this scenario would be possible with Vega/Altair.

Here, I share, the code you can copy/paste in the [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/) for try it yourself.

N.B. This is the [direct vega-editor link with the sample data](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-tDUZKYe15tgJMAaluAHID7c9wAKE+UaOUEqzE9Dke-Ti3O+1361gpQBBMfRWR-P1-vz9GAASluABeUCD0ofcQIAfluC8PCvKIbz-VZHwsX913vVY32GQDvxAr0EKQlCsJfNDvUwwgN3-PCmCAoCJyna5jgXcAez7AdFUoAA1ap6FvMi2Vgg9Dz3Z82WPW4TxTPiajoQTqJHOg8RE-cAHoxKfMiVMeL192g259OndTuX3JidF5PkAH0yUpaRIxAAASbVGEwSIdDEQgkkoZB1PUjFg1rBAzkYaNazgCB1Nc9yFACoMQxqIYApYWsbFrKxawAK0oCV5CUSca2NUAxiMUxLFsBwnBcNxPG8Xx-CsQJglCU1QFqZAbBMCQrB8QxuDHNYACFcjKfRSQSTA7moRgziTYlmwQPLOlWHQLFuad22qANoCvZU9RANlJA4DpdJQCwzA4bgCgxIFOu4LcSUW5alGvDxSFXNIABkAEkAHFBEuCcojANyITSEaxomqb3nag4WGMQJjBYKwWAGucdGJaIYgDBQQrAOBkQJVa0nWzaokiXIdqgPaogOo7kAuq7cXxRmrGZm7QRQewHoUbcdAAZRSfJnlpidCDej6SW5AAlAVuGiUGaxJkAsdiXH8cJqBYZADqLER4ILBMdHxzSBbME0fsoCKDkVfWoXQSpt0q3pwg4mQepcnkPE6j7L2QE5u7Pd5-m0nJFlxclz7g8OkGwZJz22I6mw2DMCQLpsHm1AxtJSX2ZVblJFFEg2-dCEoA7wZAKxbnJKhIqzf1dqGZYFbd87LtOn3kCsdprswW7WBDtZyWLKJqTbqO1l+gGgYVuPle+RPODh86pBsTuMOz02Z2HDwC+MGwvQF5EvnTa3szc24BZiBJbgABWQ3LtdtuF1oADQATQALWp2nXfdtYZmZ1Gb2A5gPLm90QCPR0DLCAYB2SHQlshd6n1Vay3lrHJW4Nl6r2QGYQwLB7CGFTh0QaOhpx7wLvYKwXoZaYA8NELW19PixGJm-W4X9f5Nxpi3ABKAu6s3aB0QOkhh6Y2ei-JBU8dDUF5KSGWwNsEJz9knA4EhLDGF9AQk2ax74QEIPcR4xIppwETJXO219hZO3dOLd2McQEx1ER7P24i0jk0ppHFBUtfYNCwfHOEf1EyFB1nrCwNhjAWBYGYNG289FRAgFCO+C08bLSrjXL6JAcY8LFm3d2qNgHdycRAoOrjoF8zWC6BI+86aYmkd4tBM9AZKICakRO1ppBAA).

*VEGA-LITE Code:*

```
{
  "config": {"view": {"continuousWidth": 400, "continuousHeight": 300}},
  "data": {"name": "data-5583486ec9c6448394a7b9390873045c"},
  "mark": {
    "type": "point",
    "filled": true,
    "invalid": null,
    "size": 200,
    "tooltip": {"content": "data"}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "type", "title": "Types of cards"},
    "shape": {"type": "nominal", "field": "type"},
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "def", "title": "DEF"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "atk", "title": "ATK"}
  },
  "selection": {
    "selector149": {
      "type": "interval",
      "bind": "scales",
      "encodings": ["x", "y"]
    }
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ["Cardset: 2017 Mega-Tins"],
    "subtitle": ["Here is shown the 8 cards contained in the cardset."]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.name", "as": "Name"},
    {
      "calculate": "datum.race + ' ' + ((substring(datum.type, datum.type.length-1, datum.type.length) == 's') ? substring(datum.type, 2, datum.type.length-1) : substring(datum.type, 2, datum.type.length))",
      "as": "Type"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "isValid(datum.atk) ? '' + datum.atk + (isValid(datum.def) ? '/' + datum.def : '') : 'N/A'",
      "as": "ATK_DEF"
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json",
  "datasets": {
    "data-5583486ec9c6448394a7b9390873045c": [
      {
        "id": 89631139,
        "name": "Blue-Eyes White Dragon",
        "type": "2 Normal Monsters",
        "desc": "This legendary dragon is a powerful engine of destruction. Virtually invincible, very few have faced this awesome creature and lived to tell the tale.",
        "atk": 3000,
        "def": 2500,
        "level": 8,
        "race": "Dragon",
        "attribute": "LIGHT",
        "archetype": "Blue-Eyes"
      },
      {
        "id": 46986414,
        "name": "Dark Magician",
        "type": "2 Normal Monsters",
        "desc": "The ultimate wizard in terms of attack and defense.",
        "atk": 2500,
        "def": 2100,
        "level": 7,
        "race": "Spellcaster",
        "attribute": "DARK",
        "archetype": "Dark Magician"
      },
      {
        "id": 26920296,
        "name": "Dreamland",
        "type": "2 Spell Cards",
        "desc": "This card can activate these effects depending on the monster card types on the field.\n● Fusion: Once per turn, if a monster(s) is sent from your hand or field to the GY by a card effect (except during the Damage Step): You can draw 1 card.\n● Synchro: When a monster(s) is Normal or Special Summoned (except during the Damage Step): You can increase their Levels by 1.\n● Xyz: Once per turn, during your End Phase: Destroy the monster(s) on the field with the highest Level.\nYou can only activate 1 \"Dreamland\" per turn.",
        "atk": null,
        "def": null,
        "level": null,
        "race": "Field",
        "attribute": null,
        "archetype": null
      },
      {
        "id": 80532587,
        "name": "Elder Entity N'tss",
        "type": "1 Fusion Monster",
        "desc": "1 Synchro Monster + 1 Xyz Monster\nMust be Special Summoned (from your Extra Deck) by sending the above cards you control to the GY. (You do not use \"Polymerization\".) Once per turn: You can Special Summon 1 Level 4 monster from your hand. If this card is sent to the GY: You can target 1 card on the field; destroy it. You can only Special Summon \"Elder Entity N'tss(s)\" once per turn.",
        "atk": 2500,
        "def": 1200,
        "level": 4,
        "race": "Fairy",
        "attribute": "LIGHT",
        "archetype": null
      },
      {
        "id": 23085002,
        "name": "Number 68: Sanaphond the Sky Prison",
        "type": "2 XYZ Monsters",
        "desc": "2 Level 8 monsters\nGains 100 ATK and DEF for each monster in the GYs. Once per turn: You can detach 1 material from this card; until the end of your opponent's next turn, this card cannot be destroyed by card effects, also neither player can Special Summon monsters from the GYs.",
        "atk": 2100,
        "def": 2700,
        "level": 8,
        "race": "Rock",
        "attribute": "DARK",
        "archetype": null
      },
      {
        "id": 59479050,
        "name": "Number 71: Rebarian Shark",
        "type": "2 XYZ Monsters",
        "desc": "2 Level 3 monsters\nOnce per turn, if this card has material: You can target 1 \"Number\" Xyz Monster in your GY, except \"Number 71: Rebarian Shark\"; Special Summon it, and if you do, attach 1 material from this card to it. If this card is sent to the GY: You can choose 1 \"Rank-Up-Magic\" Spell from your Deck and place it on top of your Deck.",
        "atk": 0,
        "def": 2000,
        "level": 3,
        "race": "Dragon",
        "attribute": "WATER",
        "archetype": null
      },
      {
        "id": 35261759,
        "name": "Pot of Desires",
        "type": "2 Spell Cards",
        "desc": "Banish 10 cards from the top of your Deck, face-down; draw 2 cards. You can only activate 1 \"Pot of Desires\" per turn.",
        "atk": null,
        "def": null,
        "level": null,
        "race": "Normal",
        "attribute": null,
        "archetype": "Greed"
      },
      {
        "id": 22862454,
        "name": "Proxy Dragon",
        "type": "1 Link Monster",
        "desc": "2 monsters\r\nIf a card(s) you control would be destroyed by battle or card effect, you can destroy 1 of your monsters this card points to, instead.",
        "atk": 1400,
        "def": null,
        "level": null,
        "race": "Cyberse",
        "attribute": "LIGHT",
        "archetype": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*CONFIG:*

```
{}
```